# Clingo/ASP: Best way to generate characters in a story generator

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am trying to write a story generator in Clingo.

I am trying to say "new characters can be born if existing characters give birth to them." I define new characters as `entity(&lt;int\>)`, which is the best way I could think of to representing entities. I cannot hardcode this as varying number of entities can be created in a story.

My `code` is :

```
% Create instances of time, only 3 for testing
time(0..2).

% Arrow of time flows forward
next_t(T, T+1) :- time(T), time(T+1).

% Entity 1 exists at time 0.
entity(1, 0).

% If an entity ever existed, that ID is taken and cannot be assigned to
% other entities
entity_id(ID) :- entity(ID, _).

% If an entity exists, he can give birth to a new entity
% The ID of the new entity will be 1 more than ID of all current entities.
birth(X, Y, T) :- entity(Y, T), X = #max{X1+1:entity_id(X1)}, time(T).

% At each time instant, only 1 entity can be born, as only 1 event can happen per time instant.
% This also should prevent infinite entities to be created.
:- birth(X1, _, T), birth(Y1, _, T), X1!=Y1.

% In case of a birth, create a new entiti the next time instant.
entity(X, T1) :- birth(X, _, T), next(T, T1).

#show entity_id/1.
#show entity/2.
#show birth/3 .
```

However, output is :

```
entity_id(1) entity(1,0) birth(2,1,0)
```

`entity(2, 1)` is never created, nor are `entity(3, 2)` or `entity(4, 3)`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you actually run the code? clingo very helpfully informs you that your `next` predicate is different than `next_t`. By fixing that you'll get an error for which you need to note that you're trying to take #max of a set, generate something that makes the maximum id of that set larger, which then invalidates the previous statement as the maximum we found is no longer the maximum. To get the result you wanted you could do e.g. `birth(Y+1, Y, T) :- entity(Y, T), time(T).`, but that might not be enough for your larger goal.

Comment: Thanks. The error I get after the fix is  `operation undefined: (1*X1+1)` and then a hang, which is very obtuse. I am on clingo 5.2, do more recent versions of clingo give better error messages?
Seems like generating is hard in clingo/stable models. I will have to mutate the model externally and generate the stable model based on that per time step.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be thinking that ASP statements happen *in order* from first to last or something like that.
But in fact they're just rules about a collection of atoms. The rules *always* hold. In particular, the rule:

```
entity_id(ID) :- entity(ID, _).
```

says nothing about duplicates. It just says that for every entity which has an ID `ID`, `ID` is an `entity_id`.
If you want to encode the rule that each `ID` is used once, you should write it as:

```
:- {entity(ID,_)} > 1; entity_id(ID).
```

Also you try to construct "ID's" which are "one more than all *current* entities", but there's no such thing as "current" entities. All we have to guide us are the time-steps.

Let's try writing this in a way that keeps our timesteps explicit throughout.

---

```
% Create instances of time, only 3 for testing
time(0..2).

% Entity eve exists at time 0.
entity(1, 0).

nextID(2, 0).

% If an entity existed at the previous time-step, they continue to exist
% at the next time-step (as I understand, no entity dies).
entity(ID, T) :- entity(ID, T-1); time(T).

% Any entity who was alive on the previous time-step can give birth to
% a child at time T. This child's ID is the current `nextID`
% Note this is a _choice_ rule. The entity _can_ give birth, they don't
% have to. Also we only allow at most one of these births to happen at
% each time-step.
{birth(ChildID, ParentID, T) : entity(ParentID,T-1)} <= 1 :- nextID(ChildID,T).

% Once born, an ID becomes an entity.
entity(ID,T) :- birth(ID,_,T).

% If an entity was born at the previous time-step, the nextID increases by one
% for this time-step.
nextID(ID+1,T) :- nextID(ID,T-1); time(T); entity(ID,T-1).
% Otherwise it stays the same.
nextID(ID,T) :- nextID(ID,T-1); time(T); not entity(ID,T-1).

#show birth/3.
```

Running this I find there are 5 models.

```
$ clingo entities.asp 0
clingo version 5.3.1
Reading from entities.asp
Solving...
Answer: 1

% ^ Nobody is ever born
Answer: 2
birth(2,1,2)
% ^ Nobody born at time 1. 1 births a child at time 2
Answer: 3
birth(2,1,1) birth(3,2,2)
% ^ 1 births a child at time 1 and that child gives birth at time 2.
Answer: 4
birth(2,1,1)
% ^ 1 births a child at time 1. Nobody is born at time 2.
Answer: 5
birth(2,1,1) birth(3,1,2)
% ^ 1 births two children; one at time 1 and another at time 2.
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 5
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.011s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.004s
```